# How do I get my next.js app production build to update realtime with firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

I'm new to firebase and nextjs, along with static site generation etc. I have an image album website deployed on vercel, wired up to firebase storage and firestore database.

In development everything works fine, but I can't get my production build to have realtime updates from firestore. When I add something to firestore in production it gets added, but I don't have any data read updates until next deployment.

I don't know what part I should be looking at to fix the problem, and neither which parts of code should I show to make answering this easier.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, for anyone wondering, the problem has to do [incremental static regeneration](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration). Adding revalidate to getStaticProps solved the problem.